# Pointer arithmetic within the while loop exit condition with C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, while-loop

EDIT POST ANSWER: This is NOT a pointer arithmetic issue, see answer #1

I am trying to figure out why the two programs below are NOT equivalent. I am learning pointers for the first time and I think there is something I am not understanding correctly about pointer arithmetic. I am using C++

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};     
    int *pArray = array;                    
    
    int *pArrayLast = pArray + 10; 
    
    while(pArray < pArrayLast) 
    {
       cout << *pArray << " ";
       pArray++;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now, since `*pArrayLast = pArray + 10` so I think I should be able to replace my `while` loop condition from `pArray < pArrayLast` with `pArray < (pArray + 10)`

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int *pArray = array;
    
    while(pArray < (pArray + 10))
    {
        cout << *pArray << " ";
        pArray++;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows

```
infinite while loop
```

What's going on? Why doesn't `pArray < pArrayLast == pArray < (pArray + 10)` ? Isn't `(pArray + 10)`  evaluated first in the `while` loop exit condition?

Comment: I don't follow. For what values of `n`, do you expect `n < n + 1` to be false?

Comment: `pArray + 10` is re-evaluated every time the loop condition is checked, just like `pArray` itself is.

Comment: pArray is always smaller than pArray+10. This has nothing to do with pointer arithmic.

Comment: It isn't quite infinite.   Since pointer arithmetic is signed, once 10 increments after `pArray++` sets the sign bit, the loop will terminate.   If you are on a 32bit machine, about 4-6 seconds; on a 64bit machine, it could be quite a while.

Comment: @mevets No, signed overflow is UB. A compiler could absolutely generate a program that runs infinitely.

Comment: Welp, @hamon is right. Can't believe I spent 4 hours debugging and my first StackOverflow post on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *may* just be a typo but, in your second code snippet, the `while` loop comparison will never be false because your are testing if a value is less than "itself + 10".

What you *probably* wanted is to compare the `pArray` pointer, after each increment, to its *original* value, which was a copy of the `array` address; so we can use that, instead.

The following code is 'equivalent' to your first code snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int* pArray = array;

    while (pArray < (array + 10)) { // Compare to the 'original' value plus 10!
        std::cout << *pArray << " ";
        pArray++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can not replace `pArray < pArrayLast` with `pArray < (pArray + 10)` is because `pArray` changes in while loop, which causes `(pArray + 10)` also change. When `pArray` changes, `(pArray + 10)` is not the original `(pArray + 10)` anymore.

Let's analyze the difference step by step.

If you use `pArray < pArrayLast`

```c
// before the while loop
pArray: array
pArrayLast: pArray+10 = array+10

// after executing while loop the 1st time
pArray: pArray++ = array+1
pArrayLast: (not changed) = array+10

// after executing while loop the 2nd time
pArray: pArray++ = array+2
pArrayLast: (not changed) = array+10

// ...

// after executing while loop the 10th time
pArray: pArray++ = array+10
pArrayLast: (not changed) = array+10

// pArray=array+10 and pArrayLast=array+10
// pArray<pArrayLast is no longer true
// so leave the while loop
```

If you use `pArray < (pArray+10)`

```c
// before the while loop
pArray: array
pArray+10: pArray+10 = array+10

// after executing while loop the 1st time
pArray: pArray++ = array+1
pArray+10: pArray+10 = (array+1)+10 = array+11 // << changed!

// after executing while loop the 2nd time
pArray: pArray++ = array+2
pArray+10: pArray+10 = (array+2)+10 = array+12 // << changed!

// ...

// after executing while loop the 10th time
pArray: pArray++ = array+10
pArray+10: pArray+10 = (array+10)+10 = array+20 // << changed!

// (pArray+10) always changes when pArray changes
// and (pArray+10) is always bigger then pArray
// so it becomes a infinite loop
```